# Regex to get street number with spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm still a regex newbie.

I have "nicely formatted" addresses and the data source will only give me nice Australian addresses.

I've got this far:

```
~([\w\d\-\/\.]*)\s*([\w\d '\-\.\ ()]+)~
```

Given the address,

```
123/500-550 Main Street
```

It will give me two groups (which is what I want):

```
123/500-550
Main Street
```

But I'm stuck on trying to accommodate spaces like:

```
123 / 500-550 Main Street
123  / 500-550 Main Street
123 / 500 - 550 Main Street
```

Can I maybe use a `^` and lookahead to detect the start of the street name like `[\w\d '\-\.\ ()]+` and then get everything to left of it? If so, how?

https://regex101.com/r/kG32Sz/1

Comment: Is using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) not possible?

Comment: What happens if the street names is 3 words?  What about the street number not having a range?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my current expression is ok with those scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can add whitespace to the number part (removing letters btw) and detect the street part start using positive lookahead:

```
([\d\-\/\.\s]*)(?=\s+\w)\s+([\w\d '\-\.\ ()]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG32Sz/2)

Answer (score 0):

Though generally not advisable, you could use

```
^                                # start of line
(?P<street_number>[-/\d\h]+)\h+  # capture -, \d and \h => street_number
(?P<street_name>[A-Z][\w\h]+)    # capture sth. with UPPERCASE, 
                                 # followed by \w and \h => street_name
$                                # end of line
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kG32Sz/3) (and mind the modifiers !).

---

Better use a library with ***previously known*** street names instead (or query it with the expression above, that is).
You may add other allowed characters in the class, such as `[-'.\w\h]`. Note that most characters do not need to be escaped within a class.